# Magento2 How to Display Product Custom Attribute Value In List Page

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute, custom

i have created one product custom attribute  name -> 'is-buynowbutton-show'
and i want to get that attribute value in product list page to show buy now based on product setting.

Does anyone suggest me how i can get product custom attributes value in product list page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First open attribute on admin

> Store -> Attributes -> Products

Then open your desired attribute `is-buynowbutton-show`, open tab **Storefront Properties**

In this tab you will find option "**Used in Product Listing**" make sure it is set to **Yes**

Now in your list phtml file you can use attribute like this

```
$_product->getData("is-buynowbutton-show");
```

Note: A piece of advice, do not use dash (**-**) always use underscore (**_**) in attribute code. so that you can be able to use it like this `$_product->getIsBuynowbuttonShow();`

Answer (score 0):

In product list page you will get the foreach loop with product colection. Each product of this loop is product object as **$_product**.

The you will get this value of this product custom attribute as **$_product->getData('is-buynowbutton-show')**